# KxK matrices from NxKxK tensor multiplied by rows of NxK matrix of MxNxK tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensors. One is a N batch of KxK matrices, i.e. I have NxKxK tensor called A. Then I have a MxNxK tensor called B. I want to get a new MxNxK tensor where each i'th transposed row from NxK tensor from B is multiplied by the i'th KxK matrix from A forming a new i'th transposed row of NxK tensor. And this is done for all NxK tensors from B.

Because KxK matrices from A are low-triangular maybe it will be easier to resolve this question forming A from upper-triangular matrices and do not use transpose operations multiplying rows from B by KxK upper-triangular matrices.

I attached screen to be more precise

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that solution is

```
torch.einsum('pts,tsk->ptk', B, A)
```

if `A` is upper-triangular